# Mysql Query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Below is my Table Structure

```
Table 1

id
name


Table 2

id
table1_id
```

I want the rows from table 1 which have no reference value in table 2.

Example data:

```
Table 1
id                name                       
1                  demo
2                  demo2
3                  demo3
```

Table 2

```
id                table1_id
1                   1
2                   1
3                   1
4                   3
5                   3
```

So there is no value in table 2 with table1_id 2. I want id 2 from Table 1.

Below id the query i have tried:

```
SELECT l.id FROM Table1 l WHERE l.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(r.id) FROM table2 r);
```

This is returning a proper result but its taking more than 2 minutes to process.

In table 1 i have 4000 rows and in table 2 I have 40000 rows.

Any optimisation to above query or any alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
WHERE table2.table1_id IS NULL
```

Comment: there will be no NULL value for table1_id in table 2

Comment: my local mysql has gone with this query.. :(

Comment: @Avinash: you should have indexes on columns

Answer (score 1):

Have an index for `Table1.id` and `Table2.table1_id`, then try the following query:

```
SELECT Table1.id FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1.id NOT IN (SELECT Table2.id FROM Table2 group by Table2.table1_id);
```

Comment: When I have tried to give index in second table, I got the following Error: #1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys

Comment: ALTER TABLE  `sites_check`.`domaincheckresult` ADD INDEX  `Main Domain Id` (  `nDomainID` ( 10 ) )

Comment: Try this `create index table2_table1_id on Table2 (table1_id)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to acheive is to find orphan records right?

A join that shows all the records from the first(the left) table and the matching values form the other or nulls for no matches is called a left join. I think a left join will do the same job but it is not going to be any faster. Joins are in general slower.

I found a place where it is all well explained - http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

It does not hurt to try with a join though, and tell us were your results the same as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id from table1 as t1
    left outer join table2 as t2
    on t2.table1_id = t1.id
    where t2.id is null;
```

or

```
select t1.id from table1 as t1
    where not exists (select 1
    from table2 as t2 where t2.table1_id = t1.id);
```